# Crear seguimiento de scroll en item activado

Tags: javascript, css

Estoy buscando una solución de seguimiento mediante scroll en horizontal, supongamos que la lista es demasiado larga que necesita un scroll, mi problema es que el `.active` class se pierde cuando se tiene un width corto, me gustaría hacer el seguimiento por medio de scroll a la posición activada.

Como puedo mover la scroll al `li` con class `.active` cada que cambie?.

```css
.items {
 width: 120px;
 display: flex;
 list-style: none;
 background: gray;
 overflow-x: scroll;
}
.items .item {
 padding: 2px;
}
.items .active {
 background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul class="items">
<li class="item">1</li>
<li class="item">2</li>
<li class="item">3</li>
<li class="item">4</li>
<li class="item">5</li>
<li class="item">6</li>
<li class="item">7</li>
<li class="item">8</li>
<li class="item">9</li>
<li class="item">10</li>
<li class="item">11</li>
<li class="item active">12</li>
<li class="item">13</li>
<li class="item">14</li>
<li class="item">15</li>
<li class="item">16</li>
<li class="item">17</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias usar `scrollIntoView` cada vez que seleccionas un nuevo elemento, esto hace que la barra de scroll se mueva hasta que el elemento al que le hiciste scrol sea visible un ejemplo seria lo siguiente:

```js
    const items = [...document.querySelectorAll('.item')]
    let index = 0;

    function selectPrev() {
        removeActive();

        if (index == 0) {
            index = items.length - 1;

            applyActive();
            return;
        }

        index -= 1;
        applyActive()
    }

    function selectNext() {
        removeActive();
        index = (index + 1) % items.length;
        applyActive();
    }

    function applyActive() {
        items[index].classList.add('active');
        items[index].scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "nearest" })
    }

    function removeActive() {
        items[index].classList.remove('active');
    }

    selectNext();
```

```css
.items {
    width: 120px;
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    background: gray;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

.items .item {
    padding: 2px;
}

.items .active {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
    <ul class="items">
        <li class="item">1</li>
        <li class="item">2</li>
        <li class="item">3</li>
        <li class="item">4</li>
        <li class="item">5</li>
        <li class="item">6</li>
        <li class="item">7</li>
        <li class="item">8</li>
        <li class="item">9</li>
        <li class="item">10</li>
        <li class="item">11</li>
        <li class="item">12</li>
        <li class="item">13</li>
        <li class="item">14</li>
        <li class="item">15</li>
        <li class="item">16</li>
        <li class="item">17</li>
    </ul>

    <button onclick="selectPrev()">Anterior</button>
    <button onclick="selectNext()">Siguiente</button>
```

`ScrollIntoView` es muy configurable segun las necesidades que tengas, revisa la documentacion si quieres modificar mas elementos del comportamiento general.

Documentacion de referencia: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView